# How to add combo box items from SQL db?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-express

I need to add the items to combo box from `SQL` db  .In my form am having 1 combo box(for items) and 1 `textbox` (for values). I need to load items to both from DB table and the value of `textbox` should be selected according to value of combo box.

eg:

```
combobox           textbox  
--------------------------
 Items          price  
 sss             100       
 ddd             140  
 fff             220
```

The textbox value should be selected automatically when combobox value is selected.

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("data source=PC\\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=true;Initial catalog=MyDB");
            BindData1();
}
 public void BindData1()
        {


            con.Open();
            string strCmd = "select Items from tblbill";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "items";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "items";
            comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            comboBox1.Enabled = true;

        }

 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con.Open();
           string sel = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();



           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select price from tblbill where items=" + comboBox1.SelectedValue, con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                p = dr[0] as string;
                //department = reader[1] as string;

            }

            textBox1.Text = p;
            con.Close();
        }
```

My combobox is filled with items from `tblbill` but can't able to display price value in `textbox` according to selection in `combobox`.

Please help me

Comment: `the value of textbox should be selected according to value of combo box` you should make this clearer, what's the corresponding value of textBox which can be derived from some value of comboBox? Looks like your code show that you want to get **that corresponding** value from database, right?

Comment: Don't re-use connection objects. use it in `using` statement.

Comment: hi King King,what u said is right.i want to get the corresponding value selected in combo in textbox from DB.

Comment: you are missing quotations marks in "... where item = '" + comboBox.SelectedValue + "'", con);
But I'd follow the suggestions people gave in their answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display the Selected Item price from the combobox.

Try This:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select price from tblbill where items=@itemname", con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemname",ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.Read())
            {
               textBox1.Text= dr[0].ToString();                  
            }
```

**Difference between SelectedText and Text Property of ComboBox**  n

SelectedText property from MSDN

> Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a
>   ComboBox.

while Text property from MSDN

> Gets or sets the text associated with this control.

Comment: hi thanks for ur quick reply.i want to know the difference of selectedvalue and selectedtext in combobox.  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemname",ComboBox1.SelectedText);

Comment: @rebo: you are welcome :) well see my edited answer with difference section :)

Comment: @rebo: SelectedText only gives you the portion of text which was selected(like selection we do in ms-word) Text property gives you actual itemText of the Combobox

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select price from tblbill where items=@price", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
//no need to use reader use 
var value= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();//set data type according to your use
textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
```

Make use of sqlparameter to avoide sql injection and make use of execute scalar as you are trying to get only one price for selected product

Comment: { Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue };

Comment: expected ; error in this line.{ Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue };    need help...

Comment: hi what u updated.showing same error ; expected in line   SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter("@price", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) { Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue };

Comment: @rebo - i chaged qlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter("@price", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) { Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue }; to command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()); check the answer

Comment: @rebo= i suggest you make use of ExecuteScalar rather than reader it because only one value get return from the sql query

Comment: @PranayRana: +1 Your answer is more accurate than mine, if i'm the OP i would have accepted yours.

Answer (score 1):

This example below is not exactly solves your issue but it:

- Shows appropriate way of using disposable objects such as `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`
- shows that you don't need to load Dataset, DataTable is enough in many cases
- shows how to bind `textbox` to data

Using this, you can imagine, how easy would be to load another `DataTable` with single record and bind it. Or you can manually populate text boxes.

Another option, and this is interesting, is to load a `Dataset` with two tables - 1 combo lookup and another actual data. Establish relationship between them and bind controls. Then you will not have to go to DB every time you change value in `combobox`. You will need to refresh data sometimes but everything will be happening on the client.

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection("data source=PC\\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=true;Initial catalog=MyDB");
    BindData1();
}

public void BindData1()
{
    DataTable dt = null;

    using (SqlConnection con =  new SqlConnection("data source=PC\\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=true;Initial catalog=MyDB"))
    {
        con.Open();
        string strCmd = "select Items from tblbill";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, con);
            dt = new DataTable("TName");
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "field1";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "field2";
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

    textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", dt, "field3"));

    }

}
```